# How do I build a "millions" detector in text data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to build 1 - 100 millions detector in text dataset, because in some my native language '.' and ',' is switching in meaning ('.' for thousands and ',' for cents)

Here's my data:

```
 id    Body
  1    You 're get 4500000
  2    Congrats, you receive 500000
  3    Congrats, you receive 5.000.000
  4    Congrats, you get 2.000.000,00!
  5    Your verification code is 600700800
```

Here's my expected output

```
 id    Body                                   millons
  1    You 're get 4500000                    4500000
  2    Congrats, you receive 500000           0
  3    Congrats, you receive 5.000.000        5000000
  4    Congrats, you get 2.000.000,00!        2000000
  5    Your verification code is 600700800    0
```

They are zero because it is not in the number range that desired, that is `1000000` - `100000000`

What I did is:

```
df['number'] = df['body'].str.findall(r'[0-9]').str.len()
```

then I filter:

```
df[(df['number']<9) & (df['number']>6)
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Edited, I am only have idea for filtering non zero rows, but still not solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried just using string formatting to create a different message from the `millions` column?

Comment: @Jeseph Dasenbrock I don't get your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a better `re` pattern this can be done using `Series.str.extract`

```
df_str = ''' id    Body
  1    You 're get 4500000
  2    Congrats, you receive 500000
  3    Congrats, you receive 5.000.000
  4    Congrats, you get 2.000.000,00!
  5    Your verification code is 600700800
  6    this line has no numbers
  7    this line has malformed numbers 5.00,8
  '''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), sep='\s\s+', engine='python', index_col=0)

pattern = r'((?:\d+)(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)'
numbers = df['Body'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
number_floats = numbers.str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '.').apply(float)
in_range = (1E6 <= number_floats) & (number_floats <= 1E8)
df['millions'] = number_floats.where(in_range, 0)
```

> ```
> id  Body                                    millions
> 1   You 're get 4500000                     4500000.0
> 2   Congrats, you receive                   500000    0.0
> 3   Congrats, you receive 5.000.000         5000000.0
> 4   Congrats, you get 2.000.000,00!         2000000.0
> 5   Your verification code is               600700800 0.0
> 6   this line has no numbers                0.0
> 7   this line has malformed numbers 5.00,8  0.0
> ```

It only misbehaves with multiple numbers in 1 line

## The re pattern

```
(
(?:\d+)         # a number of digits
(?:\.\d{3})*    # a `.` followed by a group of 3 digits; optional, multiple possible
(?:,\d+)?       # a `,` followed by a number of digits; optional
)
```

the `(?:` means these subgroups are not captured individually